EventData for EVENT_INSTANCE - list of all possible values
Looking to find a complete list for values retrieved by @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/[value] in SQL Server.
At the following URL, for Logon Trigger, some are given:
enter link description here
Look under XML ...
starting with "EventType" and ending with "IsPooled"
Nothing is given under DDL Triggers
enter link description here
I know that there are more then what given under Logon trigger, as I am already using some, eg EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand) in a DDL trigger
But having a complete list, best from some Microsoft source, would help very much

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#schemas-returned looks promising, but surely you looked there

This is the answer.
I did, but did not get at first what was it.
It was a link after link, but in the end - this one:
https://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2006/11/eventdata/events.xsd
